# What value will PhD give me?

Tags: phd

I'm a lecturer (I have an MSc) at university. The university wants me to do my PhD at another country (the UK). However, I didn't think about PhD before and now it is a must or they are going to change my job to something other than teaching.

I'm thinking now what value will the PhD give me after I get it? I mean what are things that will become special in my life?

Comment: What is a PhD in pictures: http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/

Comment: You'll be allowed to become a professor, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Mechanical Engineering PhD, Electrical Engineering MS, Bioengineering MS, Electrical Engineering BS in USA. I was an international student and I met my wife who was also an international student when we were B.S. In order to keep our relationship, we stayed in US as students. Last year I got my green card (No green card is very difficult to find job in US, even if international student may apply working visa. Not much company is willing to hire a temporary working visa people).

Currently, I am a contractor in a small private company. My hourly paid is as same as a B.S. student that I taught when I was a PhD student. My previous labmate who is a US citizen got a government job, the other one also citizen got a position at NASA.

PhD is almost no value to most of industries. I used my PhD title to get my current job, but this job is totally unrelated to my research. Small and middle size companies do NOT spend time to train you. They need someone knowledge more than creativity.

If you want to use a PHD title, so that you can a professor. At least in USA, you need to have a few years of post-doc training first. Moreover, there are 400 applications per assistant professor position open in my previous university (Top 100 NOT Top 10).

Do NOT do a PHD if you don't have to.

Comment: The "400 applications per position" statistic is somewhat misleading, since it is probably the same 400 applicants applying to all the open positions in the country (of which there may be hundreds as well).  It doesn't mean that only 1 in 400 applicants finds a job.  And it is generally only research universities that require postdoc experience; many smaller colleges are happy to hire fresh PhDs.  I'm sorry for your experience, but I don't think it is an accurate portrait of academia as a whole.

Comment: Typically, 'derogatory' generalizations are frowned upon by the academic community. Especially when evidence for the same is a little shaky and anecdotal.

Comment: @Naresh I just tell my real world experience.

Comment: @Nate Elderdge My background is engineering. How many small university have engineering colleges?